# ember cli serverMiddleware

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am trying to disable livereload from an addon I am creating. It's not working unfortunately, any ideas?
Here is my code:

```
serverMiddleware: function(config) {
        config.options.liveReload = false;

        browserSync({
            injectChanges: true,
            reloadDelay:   5,
            notify:        false,
            open:          false,
            proxy:         config.options.host + ':' + config.options.port || 4200
        });
    },
```